# Java application crashed due to lots of files being copied

Tags: java, crash

I have an application which copies a number of files from a directory to a certain destination. The problem is that when you select a large folder it gets more intense for the app itself and then crashes. Is there any way to make it not crash? Maybe split it up into smaller parts?

This is my code:

```
public void startProcess(File orgDir, File destDir) {

    Screen1Controller sf = new Screen1Controller();

    String selectedExtension = sf.selectedExtension; // Gets selected extension from Screen1
    String extensionType = sf.typeOfExtension; // Gets selected extension type from Screen1

    int y = 1; // This is for searching for duplicates.. See below.


    try {
        File[] files = orgDir.listFiles();

                for (File file : files) {  // Goes through the files in the given directory
                if (!file.isDirectory() && file.getName().endsWith(selectedExtension)){

                    File destinationPath = new File(destDir.getCanonicalPath() + "\\");

                    destDir = new File(destinationPath + "\\" + extensionType);  // Sets the destination path
                    destDir.mkdir();

                    System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath());  // Prints the file path


                    try{
                        String fileNameWithOutExt = file.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "");  // Gets the current file without the extension

                        File destFile = new File(destDir.getPath() + "\\" + file.getName());  // If a file of the same name exists in the dest folder


                        if (Files.exists(Paths.get(destFile.getPath())))  // Checks if there is a file with the same name in the folder
                        {
                            System.out.println("There is a duplicate.");

                            File[] destFiles = destDir.listFiles();
                            for (File destinationFile : destFiles)  // Searches through the destination folder
                            {
                                if(destinationFile.getName().startsWith(fileNameWithOutExt)){  // Checks if the selected file has the same name as the file that's going to be moved.
                                    y++;  // Increments y by 1 to keep track of how many there are of the same/similar name
                                }
                            }

                            File newFile = new File(orgDir.getPath() + "\\" + fileNameWithOutExt + "." + y + selectedExtension);  // Creates a new file with new name.

                            file.renameTo(newFile);  // Renames to a unique name and moves the file to the destination folder

                            File destPath = new File(destDir.getPath() + "\\" + newFile.getName());  // Gets the destination path for the file

                            System.out.println(newFile.getCanonicalPath());

                            Files.copy(Paths.get(newFile.getCanonicalPath()), Paths.get(destPath.getPath()));  // Renames the original file back to its original name

                            newFile.renameTo(new File(orgDir.getPath() + "\\" + fileNameWithOutExt + selectedExtension));

                        } else {
                            Files.copy(Paths.get(file.getPath()), Paths.get(destFile.getPath()));  // Moves the file to the destination folder
                        }

                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else{
                    startProcess(file, destDir);
                }
        }           

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: What *crash* has happened? Do you have any `Exception` or a stack trace?

Comment: Java applications don't crash because there are a few more files. You need to read or at least include the Exception thrown to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your program is correct and this is purely memory issue. Increase the memory settings by running program with options `-Xms 1024m -Xmx 1g`, increase the values if necessary, be aware of your total available memory. 
Will be nice to see a stack trace of exception to know for sure what caused the crash.